# dump all routes of all tables with iproute2

Tags: bash, iproute2

I want to save all routes of all routing tables.

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DUMP=dump.log

for i in `seq 0 255`;
do
    routes="`ip route show table ${i}`"
    if [ ! -z "${routes}" ];then
        echo "table: ${i}" >> ${DUMP}
        echo "${routes}" >> ${DUMP}
        echo "" >> ${DUMP}
    fi
done
```

the problems I have with this script are:

1. it iterates on all tables, and assume that the only valid table numbers are 0-255, is this a valid assumption?
2. is there a simple 1 liner for getting all routes for all tables?

Thanks

Comment: `ip route show table all`

Comment: @cburn11: why not make an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ip route list table all
```

It's written in ip route help.

Comment: You should remove the period after `all` in your example.